# sort csv column based on value of specific column with defaultdict in python

Tags: python, sorting

How could I sort a column in a csv file the way that excel will sort. below is my csv file and snippet code that I have so far. I want to sort ArrivalTime, so the particular Process and ServiceTime move along. Thank for any help or advice.

csv:

```
    Process,ArrivalTime,ServiceTime
    A,0,3
    B,2,6
    C,4,4
    D,6,5
    E,8,2
```

and my code:

```
 import csv
 from collections import defaultdict

    columns = defaultdict(list)
    with open('file.csv') as f:
      reader = csv.DictReader(f) 
      for row in reader:        
        for (k,v) in row.items(): 
          columns[k].append(v)

st = columns['ServiceTime']
at = columns['ArrivalTime']
pr = columns['Process']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using `pandas`?  It has built-in methods for handling exactly this type of situation.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe from the file, like an Excel spreadsheet
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df.sort_values('ArrivalTime')

# returns:
  Process  ArrivalTime  ServiceTime
0       A            0            3
1       B            2            6
2       C            4            4
3       D            6            5
4       E            8            2
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should use pandas...

Apart from that you don't need a defaultdict here.

Read the file and sort:

```
import csv
import operator as op

list_of_dicts = []
with open('in.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        list_of_dicts.append(line)

list_of_dicts.sort(key=op.itemgetter('ArrivalTime'))
```

Write it back out:

```
with open('out.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=list_of_dicts[0].keys())
    for i in list_of_dicts: 
        writer.writerow(i)
```